# How do I copy pages from one PdfDocument to another with itext7

Tags: java, pdf, copy, itext, itext7

I have 2 `PdfDocument`s and want to copy all pages of one pdf to the other one. Both are valid pdfs.

That's my code at the moment, but it does not add the pages:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
PdfDocument srcPdf = new PdfDocument(reader);
for(int i=1; i<=srcPdf.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
   pdfDocument.addPage(srcPdf.getPage(i));
}
srcPdf.close();
//I close the other pdf at a later moment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addPage` method is designed to process pages of the same document.

To copy pages of different documents one should use either `PdfMerger` or `copyPagesTo` functionality.

The former one works that easy:

```
    PdfDocument mergedDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destination));
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(mergedDoc);
    for(File source : sources){
        // set source pdf
        PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source));
        // merge
        merger.merge(sourcePdf, 1, sourcePdf.getNumberOfPages()).setCloseSourceDocuments(true);
        // close source
        sourcePdf.close();
    }
    merger.close();
    mergedDoc.close();
```

The latter one is straightforward as well:

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfDocument insertDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(INSERT));
    insertDoc.copyPagesTo(1, 1, pdfDoc, 4);
    insertDoc.close();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me:     srcPdf.copyPagesTo(1, srcPdf.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocument);